# apache + fastcgi - how to run processes for another user

Tags: apache-2.2, unix

I move legacy python website that works with Apache + FastCGI to VPS from shared hosting - so need to configure everything myself.

All website scripts/static/etc are stored for user 'user1' and I've installed Python using pyenv for this user. So I have a python script dispatch.fcgi as an entry poing for my app and when I run
'python dispatch.fcgi' logged in as user1 it works fine.

But Apache is running as 'www-data' user and when dispatch.fcgi is called via apache system-wide python is used and I got an error that some modules are not available (I don't want to touch system-wide python).

Is it any way I can configure Apache (or something else) to use python/etc from 'user1' - I also want to have some environment variables applied, that are defined in .bashrc for user1.
On shared hosting I see apache processes also running with some system account but somehow they are  able to use custom python/env variables.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you switch to something reasonable like WSGI? Using FastCGI for Python is weird to say the least.

Comment: @MichaelHampton For WSGI you mean mod_wsgi module in Apache?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it.